# preseed/late_command ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, automation, preseed

I'm setting up an automatic install of Ubuntu 14.04, using preseed. I tested this using a virtual machine(virtualBox machine). Everything installs fine, without any questions, but I can't quite figure out how to use the late_command at the end of the preseed file.

What I want to do, at first time, is to run start.sh script.

I tried several attempts:

Here is the Code:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/start.sh /target/home/user; in-target chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh; /home/user/start.sh
```

Also:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string chroot /target; cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh;
```

Third attempt:

```
 d-i preseed/late_command string cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; in-target chmod +x /home/user/start.sh; in-target sh start.sh
```

the script start.sh define one command:

```
#! /bin/sh 
echo "bonjour" > /home/user/bonjour_file
```

I have tried also to create a file after installation in the new machine:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done

preseed preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done
```

But it just hung at the very end of the installation. The installation was functional, but the script had not run at all and the file "postinst_user.done" had not created.

Is the newly installed file system mounted under /target? And what's the environment like at this point in the install. What would be the correct way to do this?

Here is the whole preseed file named "ubuntu.seed":

```
# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i apt-setup/extras    boolean true
# Install the Ubuntu desktop.
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect ubuntu-desktop
# On live DVDs, don't spend huge amounts of time removing substantial
# application packages pulled in by language packs. Given that we clearly
# have the space to include them on the DVD, they're useful and we might as
# well keep them installed.
ubiquity    ubiquity/keep-installed string icedtea6-plugin openoffice.org
d-i  base-installer/kernel/altmeta   string lts-xenial
####################################################################
# General
####################################################################
# Once installation is complete, automatically power off.
# d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
#d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean true
#d-i ubiquity/summary note
#ubiquity ubiquity/reboot boolean true
#ubiquity ubiquity/poweroff boolean true
# Once installation is complete, automatically power off.
# d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
#d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean true
#d-i ubiquity/summary note
#ubiquity ubiquity/reboot boolean true
#ubiquity ubiquity/poweroff boolean true
####################################################################
# Partitioning
####################################################################
# Configure auto partitioner
#ubiquity partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select Guided - use entire disk
#ubiquity partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
#ubiquity partman-auto/method string regular
#ubiquity partman-auto/choose_recipe select All files in one partition (recommended for new users)
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
####################################################################
# Locale
####################################################################
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string fr
# Optionally specify additional locales to be generated
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_US.UTF-8, nl_NL.UTF-8
###################################################################
# Localizations / Timezone
####################################################################
### Keyboard selection ###
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string fr
d-i keyboard-configuration/variantcode string
### Clock and Timezone ###
#see the contents of /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values
d-i time/zone select Europe/Paris
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean false

####################################################################
# User Creation
####################################################################
d-i passwd/user-fullname string user
d-i passwd/username string user
d-i passwd/user-password password xxxxxx
d-i passwd/user-password-again password xxxxx
#d-i passwd/user-default-groups string adm audio cdrom dip lpadmin sudo plugdev sambashare video
#d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
#d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password hPdFxI2FOMtZk
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
#d-i passwd/auto-login boolean false
####################################################################
#Network Configuration
####################################################################
#d-i netcfg/enable boolean false
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
###################################################################
# Installation Sources: Packages, Mirrors, Image
####################################################################
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname  string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu/
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean true
d-i apt-setup/mirror/error select Change mirror
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
d-i apt-setup/partner boolean true
####################################################################
# Grub
####################################################################
#d-i grub-installer/grub2_instead_of_grub_legacy boolean true
#d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
#d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true 
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# finish installation   
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note  
d-i finish-install/keep-consoles boolean false  
d-i cdrom-detect/eject boolean true 
d-i debian-installer/exit/halt boolean false    
d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean false
####################################################################
# Customization 
####################################################################
#first attempt
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/start.sh /target/home/user; in-target chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh; /home/user/start.sh
#second attempt
d-i preseed/late_command string chroot /target; cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; chmod 700 /home/user/start.sh;    
#Third attempt
d-i preseed/late_command string cp -f /cdrom/start.sh /home/user; in-target chmod +x /home/user/start.sh; in-target sh start.sh
#file creation
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done
preseed preseed/late_command string in-target touch /etc/postinst_user.done
```

And I am editing the txt.cfg (under isolinux directory) file provided below. I am editing exaclty this line `append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed keyboard
    configuration/layoutcode=fr boot=casper automatic-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet`

```
default live
label live
menu label ^Try Ubuntu Automated version By Emila
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed keyboard
configuration/layoutcode=fr boot=casper automatic-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet
label live-install
menu label ^Install Ubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label check
 menu label ^Check disc for defects
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label memtest
 menu label Test ^memory
kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
localboot 0x80
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your preseed file looks good to me in syntax. May you provide 1. the full content of your preseed file 2. the way you launch this automation process (e.g. which kernel parameters you have passed.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have edited the post to include the information you requested. My preseed file is called ubuntu.seed and is located under preseed directory in the iso file  and is been called by the kernel "append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed". what do you think went wrong?